# Problems with user inputs in java

Tags: java, input

I am new to java and I am still getting used to most of the syntax. Here I tried to get two inputs (the first one being an int and the second one a string) and later one I do some calculations with them. But when I run the program, it gives this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lan._NumberFormatException: For input string: "" 
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NuthberFormatException.java:65) 
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592) 
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) 
at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = myObj.nextInt();
        String Input = myObj.nextLine();
        String[] Inputs = Input.split(" ", 0);
        int size = Inputs.length;
        int[] a = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(Inputs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the program is assuming both inputs as the same. But how do I fix that?

Comment: Can you share an example input that produces this error?

Comment: I would normaly try to input something like 3 and in the next line 1 2 6. But it gives error after i input the first number. Even using console it gives the same error.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson It does, thank you! I didnt understand that the problem was that it wasn't inputing anything as a String

Comment: An extra `.nextLine()` (which basically reads an empty rest-of-the-line) after using `.nextInt()` will solve it.

Comment: @KevinAnderson - please open the question if you can. Note that OP is already using `nextLine()`. I know why OP is facing the problem but the answer won't fit into a comment. I missed submitting my answer by less than a second.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I can't reopen the question unilaterally, but I've cast my vote in favor...

Comment: Thanks, @KevinAnderson for the vote. Hopefully, it will be opened.